# Update the column using data from another two base tables

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update tp 
set total_cost = (select h_package 
                  from hv, tp 
                  where hh_id = h_id) +
                 (select t_package 
                  from tourism, tp 
                  where tourism.t_id = tp.t_id);
```

Comment: What is the question? And please be detailed in describing what you are attempting and the difference between your expected and actual results. If needed, include your table schema and sample data (do not post images). Setting up a minimal example in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-SXv3GHO) and posting the link back here would help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of difficult to suggest as you didn't post tables' descriptions; it would have helped if you preceded column names with tables' aliases, but you only partially did that.

It seems that you actually want to add `h_package` to `t_package` and put result into `total_cost`. If that's so, then **join** tables in the same `select` statement, e.g.

```
update tp set
  tp.total_cost = (select h.h_package + t.t_package
                   from hv h join tourism t on t.h_id = h.h_id
                   where t.t_id = tp.t_id
                  );
```

It presumes that you want to affect all rows in the `tp` table. If not, you'll have to include a `where` clause which will filter out rows you don't want to update.

Or - probably simpler - use `merge`:

```
merge into tp 
using (select h.t_id,
              h.h_package + t.t.package as total_cost
       from hv h join tourism t on t.h_id = h.h_id
      ) x
         
on (tp.t_id = x.t_id)
when matched then update set
  tp.total_cost = x.total_cost;
```

---

Once again: I don't know whether I managed to guess column names, but code I posted should get you started.